# How to effectively do unit test and static code analysis on .net codes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-analysis

Can anyone advise on how to do a effective unit test and static code analysis for .net codes.

are there any rules of thumbs to follows? And is it relevant to bring in tools like selenium etc?

There are some thing like hardcoding, uncaught exceptions etc which i hope can be sniff out during unit testing phase.

Thanks

Comment: Unit testing has nothing to do with hard coding.

Comment: I dont really understand what you ask for. unit testing and static code analysis aren't necessarily related? there are plenty of tools to use but not sure what answer you are expecting

Comment: i am basically asking about how can i effectively test my codes either through unit testing or running static code analysis tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunit is the best automated testing tool for unit testing .net applications. And the best part is you write .net code on nunit to test .net code. Please visit nunit.org for more info on how to use it.

Also if you are concerned about best code practices for .net there is something called FxCop that does a check on your code. So check it out. It's one of the best code reviewing tool available for visual studio.

Comment: Any idea on how do i integrate the FXCop to any continous integration tool so i can run it say scheduled daily and email notfiy if any issue.

Comment: Wait, FXCop is a code analysis tool. It analyzes on your source code when you run it. You want FXCop to be run on the source code everyday and report the findings to you via email? Am i understanding it right?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. Can advise further?